# Why Property must be initialized when there is auto back-end field generated

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to properties and moved from the java to kotlin. I'm struggling with the properties, I learned much about it **but initializing the properties are confusing me, when it should be initialized or when it can work without initialization.**

Let me explain it by the help of code. Below is the code which is requiring to initialize the property when the back-end field generated, before posting the code let me post the paragraph from the [kotlin official website](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields).

> A backing field will be generated for a property if it uses the
>   default implementation of at least one of the accessors, or if a
>   custom accessor references it through the field identifier.

Now here is the code below.

```
class Employee{
    var data: String // because there are default implementation of get set
                    // so there will be a back-end field.
}
```

> **So I have to initialize it else compilation error.**

**Ok I can understand it as that some one can access it so there will be no value which can produce the wrong result.**

Then I move next to understand it more, so I add custom getter.

```
class Employee{
    var data: String
    get() = "default value"
}
```

This also generate the back-end field so **compilation error to initialize it**. I can understand it as that there is no initialized value so compiler complain about it.

*May be compiler is not smart enough **`yet`** to check that there is value which is giving result for this property by custom getter so don't complain about initializing just return that value when required.*

**But there should be not a problem if any one access it then a default value is already there, then why compiler still complain?**

Then I move one step more to implement custom setter too.

```
class Employee{

    var data: String
    get() = "default value"
    set(value){
        field = value
    }

}
```

Still there is the back-end field because we have accessed the `field` so compiler generate the back-end field. 
Same error, should be initialized.

Then the final stage where it works fine as below.

```
class Employee{

    var data: String
    get() = "default value"
    set(value){

    }

}
```

Now I'm not accessing `field` in custom `getter` `setter` so there is not a back-end field. And it works fine.

So the final question when the property should be intialized? When there is a back-end field generated?

Comment: you should try data class it's same as the java bean class. so you don't need to create getter, setter and all.

Comment: @VijayMakwana I'm not asking about the solution, just asking for the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this does not compile:

```
class Employee{
    var data: String
    get() = "default value"
}
```

but this does:

```
class Employee{
    val data: String
    get() = "default value"
}
```

so maybe the compiler by stating *Property must be initialized* for the wrong declaration, wants from you to admit that `data` is something that you can not change. I say maybe.  
Now the part that does compile:

```
class Employee{

    var data: String
    get() = "default value"
    set(value){

    }
}
```

This is where you explicitly admit that whatever happens I will never set a value to `data`, and that's why the compiler feels fine.

Just to save you from more confusion, there's a lot of explaining about Kotlin in the Internet and you may find it very difficult to get familiarized with this relatively new language, but keep in mind that everything needs to be tested by you.  
I found the below code in a web page:

```
class User{
    var firstName : String
        get() = field
        set(value) {field = value}

    var lastName : String
        get() = field
        set(value) {field = value}
}
```

and it is presented as **compilable** when it's not.

Comment: `This is where you explicitly admit that whatever happens I will never set a value to data` Why I have to admit it? then what is the need of var then? I think there is something wrong from the compiler side or there is a deep thing that I don't know.

Comment: The need of `var` is obvious: **variable**. If the property is read-only it is not a variable. The compiler accepts the `var` (although it's useless) only if you admit that this is not a variable by declaring an empty setter.

Comment: Is it documented? or you are describing your experience?

Comment: The documentation is here: [Properties and Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html), but it's not extended to fit all of our questions, so practice, guessing and more practice is the solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

You kind of answered your own question. There's no backing field when you override both getter and setter, and don't access `field`.

About your "compiler not being smart enough": `get()` function is actually RAN at runtime, so writing a lot of compiler code just to evaluate if return value is static and should be injected as default is too niche of a use case.

If your getter depends on another field which is only initialized later, this would cause a lot of confusion as to what default value should be.

Consider this code, assuming value of `provider` is not defined:

```
var data: String
    get() = provider.data
```

What would be a default value? Do you want a null? Empty string? Maybe entire object initialization should crash? Explicit default value declaration is needed for that purpose.

That's where idea of `lateinit var` came to be: if You're certain you will `set` value before performing any `get`, You can use this keyword to prevent compiler errors and setting default value.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I was explore it more and got one more question that, why then `val data: String
    get() = provider.data` works fine?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Employee{
    var data: String
    get() = "default value"
}
```

`var` means there are both a getter and a setter. Because you didn't write a setter, you get the default one, which accesses the backing field. So there is a backing field, and it needs to be initialized.

> But there should be not a problem if any one access it then a default value is already there, then why compiler still complain?

Because that makes the rules simpler: all properties with backing fields must be initialized. This in turn may be because in Java fields don't have to be initialized and this is a known source of bugs. I would like to say it also avoids a possible bug, because presumably you don't actually want the setter's result never to be accessible, but initializing doesn't fix that problem.

I don't see any *obvious* problem with changing the rules so that a field only needs to be initialized when accessed in the getter, and maybe adding a warning when only one accessor uses `field`. But I may be missing something, and don't see much benefit to doing so either.